# Download Azure website and Azure database and create new TFS project

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-web-app-service

We have an Azure website and database that was published by a 3rd party. Is there a way to pull this down into Visual Studio and Team Foundation Server as a project?

I know you can publish existing projects to Azure via Visual Studio, but this site and database currently only exist in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the database by [exporting it through the portal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh335292.aspx#Export), downloading the bacpac blob and restoring it to a local SQL server.

The content of the website could also be recovered using a backup of the website (currently in preview). This should work well for all static content and scripting languages (e.g. PHP) but you will have a hard time if the original solution contained multiple projects and compiled code (attempting disassembling the code and rebuilding the solution would only be feasible in a worst case disaster recovery situation).

If there is any chance to receive the code and project meta-information through the 3rd party it is the preferred solution for all non-trivial websites.